# Java Fx in Swing Application: JFxPanel is added to JPanel and does not deploy until mouse click in the JPanel

Tags: javafx, jpanel, fxml, scene, invokelater

I am using JavaFx in Swing Application:  instance of JFxPanel is added to JPanel and it does not deploy until mouse click in the JPanel.

JavaFx Panel is with CSS and using FXML. Load XML time and CSS file time is reduced by buffering once and reuse by reading from already created.

However deployment of panel does not occur until mouse click even after code within SwingUtilities.invokeLater has been executed.

How can I make Java Fx work like normal Panel without waiting for user click.

Note: I do not want to use another JFrame and JDialog popups to display JFxPanel.

```
private void displayJFxGUI() {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


           JFxPanelInit jfxPanelInit = new JFxPanelInit();
           JFxPanel jfxPanel = new JFxPanel();

            jfxPanelInit.initAndShowGUI(jfxPanel);

            swingImageEditingPanel.add(jfxPanel);
            swingImageEditingPanel.setVisible(true);
            jfxPanel.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that displays the behavior you are describing? I have never seen that behavior, and there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code snippet you provided.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I think it may be timing related. I have a JFrame/FlowLayout, with contains a JCheckBox followed by a JFXPanel/DatePicker followed by a JTextField followed by another JFXPanel/DatePicker followed by another JCheckBox. On run the first JFXPanel does not show but the second one does. If I create a simple thread that waits 1s before doing the JFrame.setVisible(true) NEITHER of the JFXPanels show. The space in the JFrame for both JFXPanels is there but nothing inside of the areas show.  Mousing over or resizing the JFrame will cause the JFXPanels to show.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, in my main method, I have the problem I described previously if I start off with a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable()), but if I comment out the invokeLater, the JFXPanels/DataPickers display fine, ever time.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that needs to run in the FX Thread is Scene creation.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/FXPanel.fxml"));
  AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
  _fxmlController = loader.getController();

  _panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  _panel.add(_jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  Platform.runLater(() -> {
    _jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE));
  });
}
```